# How to write Algorithm for counting the coil on sensor basis

Tags: c#, python-3.x, windows, sensors

**I am stuck with two questions.
I need to write the algorithm for generation of a coil on my sensor basis i.e if the sensor is on and the force is greater than 10kN and speed is greater than 2 m/min then there is generation of coil.(we get the force and speed value from the other sensor).

2.After the generation of coil ,I want to write the algorithm for calculating the productive time of each coil.(the staring time of 1 coil to the starting time of my second coil is the productive time)**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJNpI.jpg)

Comment: Why do you put c# and python ? What have you tried so far ? We won't do the job for you, show us some good faith, if you encounter a problem coding it we will gladly help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if the sensor is active && sensor.force > 10kN && sensor.speed> 2m/min
"generation of coil"
else if the sensor is active && sensor.force < 10kN && sensor.speed < 2m/min
"register time"
call itself again (recursive function)
```

> For example, in C#:
>   use StopWatch to check the production time

```
StopWatch myWatch = new StopWatch();
myWatch.Start();
//...
myWatch.End();
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
string productiveTime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
ts.Milliseconds / 10);
```

> you can know if is the first coil or not by an external variable.
>   Hope this help for your reasoning.